# What is the exact usage of componentWillUpdate in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to this ReactJS and started learning Component Lifecycle. Now i have doubt about the `componentWillUpdate` and `componetDidUpdate`. I know that once you send `return true` from `shouldComponentUpdate` function, it will call `componentWillUpdate`. Once the component have updated then `componetDidUpdate` will call.

My question is are we really doing anything in the `componetWillUpdate` function? I hope we can't use `setState` also in that function. What is the exact use of componentWillUpdate function? When it will be useful?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The **componentWillUpdate** gives you control to manipulate the component just before it receives new props or state. I generally use it to do animations.
Let us say, I want to smoothly fade an element out of the view, before removing the dom. This helps.

```
 componentWillUpdate : function(newProps,newState){
    if(!newState.show){
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elem)).css({'opacity':'1'});
    }
    else{
      $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elem)).css({'opacity':'0'});;
    }
},
componentDidUpdate : function(oldProps,oldState){
    if(this.state.show){
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elem)).css({'opacity':'1'});
    }
    else{
      $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.elem)).css({'opacity':'0'});;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zupoj3x6/

One of the many many use cases especially when it comes to animations. The idea is to prepare for the state change. Preparation can be in many ways,

- you might want to set a variable which might be needed for the render
  for this particular state
- you might want to animate your divs or
- dispatch events to clear/set your stores.

  Endless use cases.

Comment: really nice explanation. understand something on this.

Comment: @suresh ponnukalai. Can you please accept this answer if it has helped you?

Comment: sure. I will do that after one or two days.

Comment: is it not better to do css changes by just adding a relevant className to the element in render...?

Comment: @Federico: It is. That is definitely a better option. I wanted to demonstrate animation in as short a code as possible.

Comment: Really seems not so useful

Comment: Note the "will update". It means the function is called when the component is about to update, but it gives you an opportunity to do something before. For example, I am using it in the root component of a React Native mobile app that is listening to `state.auth.isAuthenticated`. If that boolean becomes falsy, the app detects it before any additional screens are rendered, so it can boot the user out.

Comment: I suppose this function might as well do nothing...is up to the developer.